# Redirect any request which don't exist from a certain folder to that folder index.php file

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am running php5.6 on the website. I need to run php7.0 in a folder on that website. That folder is https://www.example.com/one/two/three. Then any bad request from https://www.example.com/one/two/three/* needs to goto https://www.example.com/one/two/three/index.php.

This is what I have so far.

```
server {
   listen                           80;
   access_log                       /path/to/site/logs/access.log combined buffer=256k flush=600m;
   error_log                        /path/to/site/logs/error.log warn;
   root                             /path/to/site/httpdocs/;
   index                            index.php index.html index.htm;

   #-- Deny Ips
   location / {
      include denyips.conf;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   #-- Error Pages
   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /index.php;
   location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/local/nginx/html;
   }

   #-- Folder with php7.0
   location ~ /one/two/three/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;

      location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

   #-- Main website
   location ~ \.php$ {
      include denyips.conf;
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

      # With php5.6-fpm:
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;

      fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location ~* (\.ht|\.bak|\.off|\.config|\.sql|\.fla|\.psd|\.ini|\.log|\.sh|\.inc|\.swp|\.dist)$ {
      deny all;
   }
}
```

I now have php7.0 working for all files in this folder https://www.example.com/one/two/three . I need all bad request from that folder on to goto https://www.example.com/one/two/three/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `index.php` you want to use is located in `/path/to/site/httpdocs/one/two/three/index.php`, you need to use

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /one/two/three/index.php$is_args$args;
```

in the `location /one/two/three` block. You need to use the path here, since `try_files` uses the `root` directory as the prefix when looking up files.

You are also missing the closing `}` in your question's configuration for that location block.